# EF Core DbContext and Parallel.ForEachAsync issue

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class CarRepository<Car> : ICarRepository
{
   ....
   public async Task<Car?> GetById(TId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      return await _dbContext.Cars().FindAsync(id, cancellationToken);            
   }
}
```

In the Program.cs I'm registering db and repository

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
   options.UseSqlServer("conn-string");
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

builder.Services.AddTransient<ICarRepository, CarRepository>();
```

DbContext is configured as follows

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
   public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
   {
        Database.EnsureCreated();            
   }
   ...
}
```

on the controller action I'm trying to perform parallel foreach

```
public class CarController : ControllerBase
{
    private ICarRepository _repository;
    public CarController(ICarRepository repository)
    {
       _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
        };

       var cars = new List<Car>();
       await Parallel.ForEachAsync(request.CarIds, parallelOptions, async (id, _) =>
       {
           Car? car = await _carRepository.GetById(id, cancellationToken);
           if (car != null)
           { 
             cars.Add(car); 
           }
       });

       return Ok();
    }
}
```

> **System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on
> this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is
> usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same
> instance of DbContext.** For more information on how to avoid threading
> issues with DbContext, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

I don't have any non-awaited calls on async methods.
My repository and DB contexts are registered as Transient.

"Normal" sequential for each instead of parallel works as expected, with no errors.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext* -- The message is clear enough. Do you understand what `Parallel.ForEachAsync` does?

Comment: That said, this is a very inefficient way to get a list of cars by a list of Id values. Why don't you use `Contains`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong?

As the error message indicates, your code is calling multiple methods on a `DbContext` concurrently. Specifically, it's calling `_carRepository.GetById` multiple times concurrently.

The best solution is to restructure your query/repository so that it handles bulk operations. E.g., you want a bulk-retrieve route that sends *all* the ids to the database and then gets back *all* the cars. This is generally easiest if you ditch the misguided generic repository anti-pattern and just use EF Core directly.